# How do I position the label of a graphviz subgraph cluster to be on the left?

Tags: graphviz, subgraph

How do I position the label for subgraph cluster to appear at it's left instead of being centered?

```
digraph mygraph {
    test1;

    subgraph cluster_mysubgraph {
        label = "This text should be at the left of the subgraph - not centered!";

        test2;
        test3;
        test4;
        test5;
        test6;
        test7;
    }

    test1 -> {test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7};
}
```

Comment: Btw I get errors when separating nodes with simple commas as in the last line - I replaced them with semicolons.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You may simply add [`labeljust="l";`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeljust) within your subgraph.

Comment: folks might also want to set labels to the bottom in a subgraph with `labelloc="b";`